# How to install a system on top of ZFS?

Tags: filesystems, system-installation, livecd, scientific-linux, zfs

I have a clear system with 5 hard drives, bios.

No OS installed, no formatting applied to hard drives.

I want to install a **Scientific linux (6.6 or higher) OS** on top of **ZFS** on it. What are the steps one should take to perform such installation:

1. Where Live-CD/Install-CD, that can format drives for ZFS, be found for Scientific Linux (or any other one that can do such partitioning/formatting)?
2. Where Installed of scientific Linux, that can be installed on top of ZFS be found?

Comment: I found the [ZFS->Platforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS#Platforms) Wikipedia article to be very informative. You should read into as much as you can there. I didn't see an easy solution, especially since Scientific Linux is derived from Redhat, which is not related to Gentoo, or Ubuntu; Which both have "very good" ZFS support.

Comment: Also check out: http://zfsonlinux.org/

Comment: I did not find a way to even partition to ZFS from Ubuntu or FreeBSD, but I didn't follow it with much tenacity.